# Select multiple columns with only one distinct column in SQL Server Compact Edition

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce, distinct

I've been looking through the net and all the answers I found was about using `nested selects` (Like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19034283/how-do-you-select-several-columns-with-one-distinct-column)). But SQL Server CE doesn't support nested selects.

Say I have this table

```
------------------------------
ID  |    MyText  | someField |
------------------------------
1   |   Tiger    |    A      |
2   |   Tiger    |    B      |
3   |   Lion     |    C      |
4   |   Cat      |    D      |
5   |   Lion     |    E      |
```

How can I get the distinct value from `MyText` and have `ID` in my results too.

The result would be:

```
------------------
ID  |    MyText  | 
------------------
1   |   Tiger    |
3   |   Lion     |
4   |   Cat      |
```

I tried this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT MyText, ID 
FROM mytable
```

But it applies `DISTINCT` to both columns

I tried `Group By` as well

```
SELECT ID, MyText 
FROM mytable 
GROUP BY MyText
```

but it throws this error

> In aggregate and grouping expressions, the SELECT clause can contain only aggregates and grouping expressions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can group by `MyText` and get min(id) from each group.

```
SELECT MIN(ID) ID, MyText FROM mytable GROUP BY MyText
```

Comment: Just the one I need! Thanks